# replace strings in python code and decrement number in the next line

Tags: python

I want to replace a string in a Python code.
Then, if x exists in an array, decrement the number in the next line, or remove the entire line if the number is zero.

My original file is:

```
good     ${x}
hi    1

good    ${y}
hi    2

good    ${z}
hi    3

notgood    ${t}
hi    1
```

The array:

```
p0 = [x, y, z]
```

And the python code:

```
r = open('replace.txt')
o = open('output.txt', 'w+')
for line in r:
    for i in p0:
        if i in line:
            line = line.replace("good", "yes")
            #line = line + 1
            #line = line.replace("2", "1")
    x = line
    o.write(x)
r.close()
o.close()
```

When i put those 2 lines in a comment, it works. Otherwise, no. Can someone help me to improve this code?

with comments,

I get this result:

```
yes    ${x}
hi    1

yes    ${y}
hi    2

yes    ${y}
hi    3

notgood    ${t}
hi    1
```

What I expect (and my effort (without comments)):

```
yes    ${x}

yes    ${y}
hi    1

yes    ${y}
hi    2

notgood    ${t}
hi    1
```

I just want an little idea (not necessary the whole work).
Thank you,

ADDED:
In the input file, lines can be:

```
${x} = Set Variable 1000 // won't change
${x} = Set Variable B // won't change

${t} = Set Variable 1000 // won't change
${t} = Set Variable B // won't change
```

Comment: Is the idea that `line = line + 1` would take you to the next line? Could you expand on *"doesn't work"* - what happens?

Comment: On a side note: what is p0 ?

Comment: in my opinion, yes

Comment: when i put those two lines in a comment, `line = line + 1` - `line = line.replace("2", "1")`, it works, it replaces `hello` by `how are you` but, i want to decrement numbers in the next line

Comment: @Fabian N. It's an array which contains x and other strings.

Comment: Even if that did work, you would then have moved to the next line *before* writing the current one to the output file, so you'd lose the first modification. Also the `line` at that point is just a string (presumably you're seeing a `TypeError` from the attempt to add a string and an integer - an [mcve] with the outputs would help clarify).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added what I expect in the description.

Comment: Please also add what happens instead - again, see [mcve]. It's not clear why you expected that `line = line + 1` would read another line from the file. Some broader context (*why* you are doing this) may also help find an appropriate solution).

Comment: @jonrsharpe my EDIT is cleaner like this. Thank you!

Comment: An explanation what format the second line has is still missing. Is it always the same length "hi"? Are there going to be more numbers there? etc...
(See below for an idea on how to accomplish that)

Comment: Yes, always the same length. I just want to decrement the number, or delete the whole line, if number = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got a bit carried away and ended up writing your code for you...

**Please** read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time before posting as this is considered unpolite otherwise...

```
def magic(line):
    # returns the first number in that line
    return [int(s) for s in line.split() if s.isdigit()][0]

p0 = ["x", "y", "z"]

# open the input file
with open('replace.txt') as f:
    # read all lines as array
    content = f.readlines()

    # for all strings we are looking for
    for i in p0:
        # loop over all lines
        j = 0
        while j < len(content):
            # if the current line contains the word we are looking for
            if "${"+i+"}" in content[j]:
                # replace "good" with "yes"
                content[j] = content[j].replace("good", "yes")

                # somehow find the number we want to decrement in the next line           
                magic_number = magic(content[j+1])-1

                if magic_number == 0:        
                    # delete the next line
                    del content[j+1]
                else:
                    # decrement the number
                    content[j+1] = content[j+1].replace(str(magic(content[j+1])), str(magic_number))

                    # skip the second line
                    j += 1

            # go to next line
            j += 1

    with open('output.txt', "w+") as o:
        o.writelines(content)
```

This creates an output file that look like this:

```
yes     ${x}

yes    ${y}
hi    1

yes    ${z}
hi    2

notgood    ${t}
hi    1
```

Comment: Thank you @Fabian N. It helps me. I put a modification in description. It's cleaner like this.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am not used to Python syntax. I just want to use this line `return int(line.split()[1]) if line.split()[0] == "text"` to get the number instead of `return [int(s) for s in line.split() if s.isdigit()][0]`, if the second word is text. Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: That would be `return int(line.split()[1]) if line.split()[0] == "text" else [int(s) for s in line.split() if s.isdigit()][0]` ?
But why would you need that? The second line selects the first number and your new line tries to parse the second word as a number if the first one was "text" so it will return the same as the second line...

Comment: Thank you @Fabian N. the file is huge so, i forgot to mention other details. Can you see ADDED section in the description, please? (as usual, just need an idea (i am new in Python))

Comment: As I have no idea what your added lines are supposed to mean: Sry but that's slowly escalating into a whole parser. I would recommend starting learning more python or higher someone to implement it for you.

Comment: when I run, i get `IndexError: list index out of range`. When, i debug, it says that the "problem" is in 'B' (ADDED section)